# Inherit Shell Class for Container Use

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, stl, containers

Would it be considered good practice to have a group of related classes all inherit from the same (essentially empty) class, so the client can organize all of the instances into one container?

For example:

```
class One : public Foo { }
class Two : public Foo { }
class Three : public Foo { }
```

So later I can do `std::vector<Foo*> myClasse`s.

If not, what is considered a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the standard practice for implementing polymorphic types. However, it is unusual for the base class to be empty. Apart from anything else, it MUST implement a virtual destructor, and normally there are other (probably pure) virtual functions that must be provided in order to do anything useful.

Comment: Right. Base classes without virtual methods make no sense

Answer (score 1):

As long as you add a virtual destructor to `Foo` so that you can `dynamic_cast` later, you should be okay.